# How to put \dots in center of two-columns

Tags: tables, align, alignment

I want to have `\dots` as well as the text `no model` in the center of the two most right columns of my table. For now this is my code:

```
  \begin{center}
    \captionof{table}{truth table and mental models of an implication}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc|cc}
     A & B & A \rightarrow B & & \\ \hline
     1 & 1 & 1 & \Circle & \triangle \\
     0 & 1 & 1  & \dots &\\
     0 & 0 & 1 & \dots &\\
     1 & 0 & 0 & no & model
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: You should use `\multicolumn{2}{c}{...}`.

Comment: `\rigtarrow`, `\triangle` (and I guess `\Circle`, however that is defined) are math-mode commands. Please do not ignore the dozens of errors coming from this code.

Answer (score 4):

Or you use just one column at the end of table where "circle" and "triangle"  are spaced apart by `\quad`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
 \begin{center}
    \captionof{table}{truth table and mental models of an implication}
    \begin{tabular}{*{3}{w{c}{3em}} |c}
     A & B & A $\to$ B  &           \\ \hline
     1 & 1 &    1       & $\bigcirc\quad\triangle$   \\
     0 & 1 &    1       &   dots    \\
     0 & 0 &    1       &   dots    \\
     1 & 0 &    0       &   no model
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{center}
    \captionof{table}{truth table and mental models of an implication}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc|cc}
     $A$ & $B$ & $A \rightarrow B$ & & \\ \hline
     1 & 1 & 1 & $\Circle$ & $\triangle$ \\
     0 & 1 & 1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\dots}\\
     0 & 0 & 1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\dots}\\
     1 & 0 & 0 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{no model}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
```

should do the trick.